# Bookself type grid design

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, grid

I am looking into designing a grid that resembles a bookshelf that will house icons for PDF files.  I got my idea for it from the iBooks interface except I would like to make some appearance changes. I was curious are there any plug ins for Visual Studios 2010 that I can use in ASP.net and Visual Basic that will allow me to create a grid that resembles a bookshelf?

Thanks :)